# Unit test case for SpringBatch job

Tags: junit, spring-batch

I've written below SpringBatch job, it will read data from source table, process and write data into target table. The functionality is working as expected but I need to write Junit test cases for SpringBatch job. Can anyone help me out how to write JUnit test cases for SpringBatch job?

Here are the piece of code

```
@Bean(name = Constant.CREATE_JOB)
    public Job testJob() {
    Job job = null;
    try {
        Flow flowOne = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>(Constant.FLOW_ONE)
            .start(truncateTableStep())
            .on(Constant.FAILED)
            .fail()
            .from(truncateTableStep())
            .on(Constant.COMPLETED)
            .to(firstStep())
            .next(secondStep())
            .build();

        Flow flowTwo = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>(Constant.FLOW_TWO)
            .start(thridStep())
            .next(fourthStep()).build();

        job = jobBuilderFactory.get(Constant.CREATE_JOB)
            .listener(createJobListener)
            .start(flowOne)
            .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
            .add(flowTwo)
            .end()
            .build();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        log.error("Exception while building Create job.. {}", exception.toString());
    }
    return job;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step firstStep() {
    Step step = null;
    try {
        step = stepBuilderFactory.get(Constant.POPULATE_STEP)
            .<InputModel, InputModel>chunk(Constant.CHUNK_SIZE_HUNDERED)
            .reader(createJobReader.createReader())
            .processor(createJobCommonStepProcessor)
            .writer(testWriter.testWriter())
            .faultTolerant().skipLimit(10).skip(Exception.class)
            .retryLimit(3)
            .retry(TransientDataAccessException.class)
            .listener(retryListener).build();
    } catch (final Exception exception) {
        log.error("Exception in the populate first Step Create Job: {}",
            exception.toString());
    }
    return step;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step secondStep() {
        ........
    }
    @Bean
    public Step thirdStep() {
        ........
    }
    @Bean
    public Step fourthStep() {
        ........
    }
```

Comment: SO is not a free coding service where people will write stuff for you. It is for help resolving specific issues or problems. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @InchHigh Have you gonna through my code? I wanted to know how to write junit test cases for SpringBatch job. I know nobody will give free services.

Comment: A good starting point is the [End-To-End Testing of Batch Jobs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/testing.html#endToEndTesting) section from the reference docs. It shows how to write JUnit tests for Spring Batch jobs with a code example.

Comment: Traditional Junit unit tests are usually meant to test java code's business logic i.e. you verify output for a fixed inputs...this kind of unit test is usually not relevant for Spring Batch jobs because business logic is not very isolated or complicated. If you have such components in your job , you can do traditional unit tests ..rest would mainly be end to end testing or testing execution of specific steps.

Comment: Thank you @SabirKhan for explanation. I will write testing execution of specific steps